Why can't I connect to this Kafka broker inside a Docker container?
Similar questions have been asked before, however having read through the information on each of them I don't believe any of the existing questions provide an answer in this case. This is partly because Kafka changed to using Kraft rather than Zookeeper, which means many older questions are now of limited relevance.
I am trying to spin up a single Dockerized Kafka Broker which operates in "broker" mode, meaning it functions both as a controller and a server.
This is my docker-compose.yml file.
services:
  broker:
    image: apache/kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    networks:
      - kafkanet
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,CONTROLLER://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@localhost:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3

networks:
  kafkanet:
    name: kafkanet

docker ps reports that port number 9092 is forwarded from the host.
C:\Users\user\Docker\kafka>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                     NAMES
a1e3717962b0   apache/kafka:latest                                      "/__cacert_entrypoin…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp    broker

I'm not able to connect to it using Conduktor Console, which is itself a Dockerized application.
I also cannot connect from the Docker container host. (The computer running Docker.)
Example Python script:
from confluent_kafka import Consumer
from confluent_kafka import Producer

def main():
    producer = Producer(
        {
            "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
            
        }
    )

    producer.produce("example-topic", "example-payload")
    producer.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Running this produces an error:
localhost:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 2ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)

I'm about 50 % sure part of the problem is two listeners are required. One where the port is forwarded from the Docker Host to the Docker container, and one where the port is used for communication between Docker containers on the same Docker Network.
Edit: Hmm... actually... that doesn't make much sense. The Dockerized Conduktor application is on its own seperate Docker Network, and so it should be.
I've forgotten how it is supposed to be setup. I tried playing around with a few variations of the configuration and go nowhere.
To break the config down:

We can ignore CONTROLLER on port 9093, because this is used for communication between Kafka brokers/servers as part of a cluster. Since there's only a single broker/server here, this isn't relevant.
Port 9092 is associated with a plaintext listener. It listens on (binds to) address localhost:9092. localhost here means "the Docker Container itself". Since port 9092 is forwarded to the Docker host, I would assume this should work.
The advertized address is localhost:9092. This is the address the Kafka Broker will dispatch to any application which requests the addresses from the bootstrap process. This will be passed to the Python application. From the point of view of Python, localhost means the Host machine, but since port 9092 is forwarded to the Docker Container, I would assume this should also work.

Hence my confusion.

Here is another example configuration which I have tried using:
services:
  broker:
    image: apache/kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    networks:
      - kafkanet
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,CONTROLLER://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@localhost:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3

networks:
  kafkanet:
    name: kafkanet

In this case, I set the address of bootstrap.servers to localhost:29092 in the Python code.
Again, no luck. In this case the exact error is:
2e7bd03ad613:29092/1: Failed to resolve '2e7bd03ad613:29092': No such host is known


Why did you delete your question from yesterday? It's the exact same problem. Please refer duplicate post section "Client (or another broker) in a container"

The correct configuration is:
(note the corrected hostname for EXTERNAL://broker:29092)
services:
  broker:
    image: apache/kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    networks:
      - kafkanet
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,CONTROLLER://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@localhost:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3

networks:
  kafkanet:
    name: kafkanet

This, by itself, is not enough, because only containers on the same Docker Network can resolve the hostname broker. If there are more than 1 Docker Networks in existence, then those networks will need to be connected together using a proxy. See this question and answer here to find out how to do that.

We use   extra_hosts:       - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" , then target to  host.docker.internal:29092

KAFKA_LISTENERS having any bound hostname as localhost limits connections to within the container (meaning Conducktor or another container within that network won't work, regardless of a "proxy"). Remove any hostnames from the config, as the official example shows, or use 0.0.0.0 to bind to a non internal interface. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/docker/examples/docker-compose-files/single-node/plaintext/docker-compose.yml#L31

@OneCricketeer not sure how to interpret your comment here - are you suggesting to leave 0.0.0.0 and remove localhost from the other two KAFKA_LISTENERS?

By default, when you have format PROTOCOL://:PORT, then 0.0.0.0 will automatically be injected by the container start-up script. Therefore, I'd recommend removing any host/IP.

@OneCricketeer that's a great tip - thanks for sharing
